# Wiring 3 led lights to a timer switch

Tags: led

My goal is to take a typical white clock and make it light up green at 3pm, yellow and 6pm and red at 9pm

I'm guessing I'm going to need 6 red led lights, 6 yellow led lights and 6 green led lights

What I'm not sure about is how something on a timer switch would be wired up, would I use transistors, diodes or something else

The clock is run off of 2 AA batteries

Comment: Complexity is added in sensing the big and little hands at those positions to advance the light sequencer which might be more than you expect , then the LEDs will consume more power than the clock itself normally draws reducing the life of the batteries significantly.  So it becomes a problem.

Comment: I can add more AA batteries, just tell me how it's done and I'll figure what I'm missing

Comment: you would be missing about 2 batteries per day.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist do they still make clocks with big and little hands?  If so, does anyone under 40 know how to read them?  Is it 3:15 or quarter after 3?   I'm pretty sure the clocks with big and little hands only need one AA battery.  Dem dare new fangled clocks are the ones dat need two AA batteries.

Comment: Its my guess of an old White analog clock, which in old technology took 2 AA's but yes modern ones work on advanced low voltage logic.with 1 cell,

Comment: Yeah its an old clock, but I'm guessing the timer part of the board would be the length of the capacitors to keep the light on and the relay open

Comment: OLd is relative.  **THIS** is an **OLD** alarm clock:  http://www.ancientpages.com/2016/05/06/ancient-greeks-invented-alarm-clocks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would I use transistors, diodes or something else

Seeing LEDs are diodes, we'll go with a yes to diodes.
Transistors?  Very likely if you want to use the clock's LED driver.
You would configure the transistors as logic gates.
The "something else" could be resistors.

[image]

Your clock would need to be a digital clock with 7 segment digits.
You would need to know the pinout for the 7 segment LED driver.
You would need to know the driver's current and voltage for each segment.

You would drive the logic gates with with two of the clock's segments.
Build a logic table for the segments when the hour digit is a three, six, or nine. You need a logic combination that will have a unique output for each of these three digits. The outputs of the logic gates would drive another transistor that turns the LEDs off and on.  OH!  Look, more diodes!

[image]

It's not going to be easy to use the drivers in the clock.

Your best bet would be to use a microcontroller with a realtime clock to drive the red, yellow, and green LEDs.   It will work with any type of clock, analog or digital.